# JMS Bridge existing queue messages

Tags: java, jms, tibco

Is it possible to setup a JMS Bridge to bridges existing JMS messages from one queue to another. I have the bridging working for new messages, but if the messages already exist in the source queue then they don't get bridged tot he destination queue.

Is there any way to make this happen?

Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Bridge only can take effect on the messages that are flowing into the source, not those that are already in the source.